# Query where list has item/object in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Using Realm in Swift (I am still using the version just before v1.x):

I have this class

```
class Event: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String? = nil
    dynamic var creator: User?
    let members = List<User>()
}
```

How can I find all events with the member "User A" (I have the id of the User A).

I tried something like this but doesn't really work:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY members.id == %@", userA.id)
eventsWithUserA = realm.objects(Event).filter(predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the latest version, hopefully you're at least using version 0.100 or higher. If so, you can use Realm's [inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) feature to do this:

```
class User: Object {
   let events = LinkingObjects(fromType: Event.self, property: "members")
}
```

After implementing this, `user.events` will return a `List` of every `Event` object in which the `user` object is in its `members` property.

```
let eventsWithUserA = userA.events
```

Hopefully this should eliminate the entire need to manually perform a query for what you're trying to achieve here.

Let me know if that doesn't work for you!